# Remove Optional string for date in UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, swift3

Happy New Year, all!

How do I get a `datePicker` text to show like this `Jan 1, 2017` instead of `2017/1/1`? In my PlayGround, it looks as expected but in my simulator or console, it looks not expected.

```
// createDatePicker():
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

// donePressed():
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
let fromString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: fromString) // I dont need time but got Jan 1, 2017, 12:00 AM in playground
datePickerText.text = "\(date)"
print("\(date)") // in console: Optional(2017-1-1 00:00:00 +0000)
```

I need to get rid of the `Optional()` but not sure how to convert `Date!` to `String!`. How to achieve getting the text to be `Jan 1, 2017`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just format your date how you want it to be, like this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
let fromString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
print(fromString) // Jan 1, 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you converting Date to date String: -

```
let fromString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: fromString) //Avoid this line in your code
```

then no need to change again date string into date try below code: -

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy" //Date Formatting
let date = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
datePickerText.text = date
print(date)
```

**Output:-**

```
 Jan 1, 2017
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this!

```
   let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateformat = "MMMM dd,YYYY"
```

if there is any label to which your are trying to show the date format then,

```
label.text = formatter.stringFromDate(datepicker.date)
```